# UITableView search bar issue

Tags: iphone, ios5, tableview, searchbar

I have a table view, and a search bar in it. It seems that I've written the code correctly, but when I enter something in the search bar, there are no results (even if there should be).

```
@interface PlaylistViewController : UITableViewController 
<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) Playlist* playlistTab;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *displayItems;

@end


@implementation PlaylistViewController 
@synthesize searchBar = _searchBar;
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize playlistTab = _playlistTab;
@synthesize displayItems = _displayItems;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self setPlaylistTab:appDel.playlist];
    _displayItems = _playlistTab.collection;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_displayItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"songCell"];
    Song* song = [_displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = song.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = song.artist;

    return cell;
}

-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    if ([searchText length]==0) {
        [_displayItems removeAllObjects];
        [_displayItems addObjectsFromArray:_playlistTab.collection];
    } else {
        [_displayItems removeAllObjects];
        for (Song *song in _playlistTab.collection) {
            NSRange rangeTitle = [song.title rangeOfString:searchText     options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            // NSRange rangeArtist = [song.artist rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (rangeTitle.location != NSNotFound) {
                [_displayItems addObject:song];
            }
        }
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

What should I do in order to get this working properly?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is almost same, try this too

```
 for(int i=0;i<[_playlistTab.collection count];i++){
      NSLog(@"entered here 1");
      Song *song = (Song *)[_playlistTab.collection objectAtIndex:i];
      NSRange rangeTitle = [song.title rangeOfString:searchText     options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
      NSLog(@"%@",rangeTitle);
      if(rangeTitle.length != 0) {
          NSLog(@"entered here 2");
          [_displayItems addObject:song];
      }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work as well. My guess here - is that I have messed up something with the connections.

Comment: Did you see the comments that printed using NSLog?

Comment: So I think the search bar is not connected well. In IB, check you connected 'searchBar' and also you set the delegate as searchBar.delegate = self; I think by setting delegate your issue will be solved.

Comment: Does the -(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText method invoked when you tapped on search button, Put a NSlog right after that function. Also try this searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES; If it also failed delete your searchBar from IB and drag a new one. Then do connections and all other things properly

Comment: sadly, no. I didn't had enough time these days to keep working on the project. As this will be my exam project, I am totally going to invest some time in it and rebuild the view, maybe. It is just a pair of hours. Maybe I'll add a generic view and insert a table view in it, coz when I did that in a sandbox project, it began working properly.

Answer (score 1):

It sort of looks like it would work, but the approach differs significantly from what [apple suggests](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  I suggest you modify a few things:

1) Create a search results model.  It's just like your _displayItems, but contains a subset of them that match the search.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *searchResultDisplayItems;
```

2) Implement - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString.  Do your searching there:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [searchResultDisplayItems removeAllObjects];
    // now we don't have to throw away the model all the time
    for (Song *song in _playlistTab.collection) {
        // and so on, your search code as you wrote it,
        // but when you find a match...
        [self.self.searchResultDisplayItems addObject:song];
    }
    return YES;
    // no need to explicitly reload data now.
    // answer YES and the search vc will do it for you
}
```

3) When the table asks for a count, decide which model to use based on which table is asking

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // it's less typing to ask if tableView == self.tableView, but for clarity,
    // I'll ask the converse question about which table we're using

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.self.searchResultDisplayItems count];
    } else {
        return [self.displayItems count];
    }
}
```

4) When the table asks for a cell, decide which model to use based on which table is asking:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"songCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSMutableArray * myModel = (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)? self.searchResultDisplayItems : self.displayItems;
    Song* song = [myModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = song.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = song.artist;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I did everything as you said, but now the table view is empty.

Comment: @nemesis, I see another problem.  We need to allocate cells if they don't get dequeued.  Will edit.

Comment: If you don't get expected results.  Add a few NSLogs and let me know what you see.  Make sure your model starts out with some songs in it,, 2) make sure your search code finds something, etc.  But I think that cell non- allocation was clearly a problem.

Comment: also, be sure to comment out your search method.  It deletes your model.

Comment: I've deleted it after inserting the new method. And the playlist is still not showing.

Comment: I think I'm going to start building this mvc from scratch.